# How do I input a number into function to output a word?

Tags: c++, function, input, iostream

I'm having trouble with understanding how cout works. I'm writing a program that reads numbers and turns each number into the Chinese version of the number.

Whenever it couts the function a handful of numbers come out after it. ex. yi6296576

Why does this happen?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int M(int manUp){
    if (manUp == 0) cout<< "ling";
    if (manUp == 1) cout <<"yi";
}

int main () {
    int num;
    cout << "put number\n";
    cin >> num;
    cout << M(num) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is your compiler showing you a warning message when you try to compile this program?

Comment: Basic grammar corrections. Made the question more specific.

Answer (score 0):

You told it to, and you appear to be ignoring compiler warnings.

Your `M` function is specified to return an `int`, but you have no `return` statement so it ends up returning whatever garbage what in memory. Your compiler should have complained about no return statement.

Your `M` function writes your strings to `cout`, and `main` writes the value returned from `M` to `cout` immediately thereafter. So even if `M` returned a reasonable value, that value would still be written to `cout` right after the string.

To fix this, return a proper value from `M`, then perhaps write a space or a newline to `cout` before writing that returned value to separate it from the string.

Comment: Yea, I'm new to this. Thanks for the advice! how would you put it in to action? Also, why does the comment section not go to new a new line when i press enter? I wanna put up an example of what you said but I don't know how to display it :/

Comment: Start by asking yourself whether `M` should return a value at all, and if it should what should it be and what do you want to do with it.